# Redirect to Post List by Taxonomy on User Selection of Taxonomy Dropdown?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

> *(**Moderator's note:** The original title was "drop down taxonomy")*
>
> I want to add a drop-down box filled
>   with my custom taxonomies, so when
>   someone selects any value, it
>   redirects to corresponding page.  I
>   tried out this code, which worked
>
> `<?php  wp_dropdown_categories( array(
>   'taxonomy' => 'name of taxonomy' ) );
>   ?>`
>
> The problem is I want a the page to
>   redirect without the user needing to
>   press any buttons. How can I do this?

this question was resolved but i want to modify further, i want to add a shortcode, so that i can also call drop-down-list into my post, i tried this but not working
`add_shortcode('drop','the_taxonomy_dropdown');`

but when i call this in my post `[drop="location"]` its not working,
whats the problem?

Comment: The shortcode issue was discussed in the chat room, [first in the general room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/conversation/wpse-4878-first-part), then [in a specific room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/163).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi **@ntechi:**

Here's a function I wrote which I named `the_taxonomy_dropdown()` to give you what I think you are looking for.

```
function the_taxonomy_dropdown($taxonomy) {
  $id = "{$taxonomy}-dropdown";
  $js =<<<SCRIPT
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("select#{$id}").change(function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).val();
  });
 });
</script>
SCRIPT;
  echo $js;
  $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
  echo "<select name=\"{$id}\" id=\"{$id}\">";
  foreach($terms as $term) {
    echo '<option value="';
    echo get_term_link(intval($term->term_id),$taxonomy);
    echo '">' . "{$term->name}</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";
}
```

You can put `the_taxonomy_dropdown()` in your theme's `functions.php` file and call it from one of your theme's template files like so:

```
<?php the_taxonomy_dropdown('name of taxonomy'); ?>
```

Notice I didn't use `wp_dropdown_categories()` because it sets the `<option>`'s values to `term_id` instead of the term's permalink. You need the permalink in order to set the `window.location.href` on the client end. Had we used `wp_dropdown_categories()` it have would added more complexity; it would have required issuing an HTTP GET request with `term_id` to a page on the server that would then redirect to the term's permalink. But it's much easier to just build the HTML `<select>` ourselves as I did *(and it's more peformant, since it doesn't take an extra HTTP request.)*

Of course, be sure to remember `wp_enqueue_script()` jQuery in an `'init'` hook, also in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('init','jquery_init');
function jquery_init() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Comment: hey thanks its working
but i have one more question,
i want this to be displayed on my home page, but my home page is not a static page,
how can i do that??
i tried to put a `<div>` tag in index.php but it is matching with my page, do you have any idea how can i do that?

Comment: @ntechi - Just put `<?php the_taxonomy_dropdown('name of taxonomy'); ?>` in your `index.php` just like you would with any theme template file, no need for a `<div>`. Or are you asking about CSS or layout?  If your question is about CSS or layout that's a question for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: might be a css question, but just check this image
http://i55.tinypic.com/bgvkgx.jpg
in this image check the hello text, it is not coming as the next post is coming
i mean that it should be wrapped into a box just like the post,
how can i do that?

Comment: @ntechi - I'm sorry, I do not understand your problem. It seems I answered your main question but now you are asking about something different? If so you really need to post a new question, not ask other questions as follow up. I think this is the second time you've asked me a different follow up question in the comments so I think it's fair of me to mention etiquette here (next comment.)

Comment: (from previous comment.) It's not very courteous to make the person who went to all the effort to write up a nice long answer to feel obligated to answer all your follow up questions *on other topics*. We are here to write one good answer per page, not to open a one-on-one free support service for others who are getting paid by their clients *(you can, of course, hire and pay some of us if you really need that level of support. :-)* I hope you don't take this as me being rude but maybe you are not aware that we are all just volunteers giving freely of our own limited spare time?

Comment: sorry for asking a different question, but both questions are related to each other from my point of view cause i just want the drop down list over there,
any ways my main question is been solved,so anyways thanks one more time

Comment: @ntechi - If you stretch it, everything in WordPress is related. :)  But I do thank you for understanding. I come here and write answers when I should be doing client work because I enjoy helping, and I feel obligated to follow up if my answer is incomplete or even wrong, but when my answer is correct I feel like my help was taken for granted so when that happens I'd rather say something and clear the air than keep it inside. Better for you (and others) to post another question because then you can get more people to answer and you can reward us all with more points! Thanks again.

Comment: hey same related question one more i have,
currently the code which you provided me is working great,
but if suppose i want something like this then
i have 2 custom taxonomies, location and courses, 
so i ll have two drop down menu,
Courses: and Location:,
but now i will select first courses and den location and then it will redirect me to the page, where it will display the posts which has both the taxonomies i.e selected course and location
is this possible????

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - Added some example code as an answer to show how the JS can be reworked.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this problem again today, that is, the dropdown element returned by `wp_dropdown_categories()` setting option values to the term's ID..

Now whilst this makes the dropdown a little useless for filter dropdowns or jump menus, it is actually possible to rejiggle the JS used so it works "as is"...

Here's a basic example, which is based on the code posted above.

```
function the_taxonomy_dropdown( $taxonomy = '', $query_var = '' ) {

    if( empty( $taxonomy ) )
        return;

    if( empty( $query_var ) )
        $query_var = $taxonomy;

    $select_id = "{$taxonomy}-dropdown";
    $url_base = get_bloginfo('url') . "/$query_var/";
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("select#<?php echo $select_id; ?>").change(function(){
            var term = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
            window.location.href = "<?php echo $url_base; ?>" + term;
        });
    });
    </script>

    <?php
    wp_dropdown_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'id' => $select_id ) );
}
```

**NOTE:** This examples JS assumes you are using pretty permalinks.

If your taxonomy uses a query var that differs to the taxonomy slug you pass into the function, simply add the query var as the second parameter..

```
the_taxonomy_dropdown( 'post_tag', 'tag' );
```

Please note, this is just an example to show you how to work around the issue with `wp_dropdown_categories` and custom taxonomies by making changes to the JS.

Also for reference, there's a ticket here that was due for a patch.
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13258

Comment: ok,
but how can i get two taxonomies drop-down box, what i want is when a user comes to my site, he will select one value from first drop-down then second value from second drop-down and when the user will hit search, then it should search the posts and give the display of the posts which contains the keyword

Comment: You'd place the two select boxes into a form and add a submit button (ya know, like a search form). Not that i think that will work, i don't think it's possible to query two custom taxonomies at once, not using GET requests at least..